# Remove duplicated permuted rows in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have one Pandas DF with three columns like below:

```
  City1 City2  Totalamount
0     A     B         1000
1     A     C         2000
2     B     A         1000
3     B     C          500
4     C     A         2000
5     C     B          500
```

I want to delete the duplicated rows where (city1,city2) =(city2,city1). The result should be

```
  City1 City2  Totalamount
0     A     B         1000
1     A     C         2000
2     B     C          500
```

I tried

```
res=DFname.drop(DFname[(DFname.City1,DFname.City2) == (DFname.City2,DFname.City1)].index)
```

but its giving an error.

Could you please help

Thanks

Comment: kindly consider adding the actual data rather than the images, it helps in reproducing your problem and solving the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sort first, then drop the duplicates:

```
import numpy as np

cols = ['City1', 'City2']
df[cols] = np.sort(df[cols].values, axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: This can completely destroy the data. All other rows for which there are no duplicates will be affected too

Comment: @suicidalteddy Given that the de-duplication doesn't care about ordering, it really shouldn't matter whether in the end ('City1', 'City2') is represented as ('A', 'B') or ('B', 'A'). I provided an answer that de-duplicates the DataFrame based City1 & City2, regardless of the order of the pairing, and total amount. This seems to be the logic necessary, and if it's not, the sample data should have given more edge cases to test.

Comment: i would have resorted to `np.sort()` here. :D

Comment: Thanks, it worked and deleted all rows that are duplicated as ('A', 'B') or ('B', 'A')

Answer (score 1):

If the entire dataframe follows the pattern you show in your sample, where:

- All rows are duplicated like (A, B) and (B, A)
- There are no unpaired entries
- CityA and CityB are always different (no instances of (A, A))

then you can simply do

```
df = df[df['City1'] < df['City2']]
```

If the sample is not representative of your whole dataframe, please include a sample that is.

Comment: Thanks, it also worked. What if there were non-duplicated rows in the data, what will be the solution?